# How can I find in a Db with multiple conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, conditional-statements, acl

I nee to extract from my database all with this condition

```
$result = $this->Acl->Aco->find(
            'all', 
            array(
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Aco.alias'=>'controllers'
                )
                ),
            array('order' => 'Aco.lft ASC', 'recursive' => 1));
        debug($result);
```

This work!
But now I would like to extract data for the row where Aco.alias is egal to 
1. Controller
2. admin_index
3. admin_edit
4. admin_del

And this I can not do this. I tried the following, but it only extract the last conditions

```
$result = $this->Acl->Aco->find(
            'all', 
            array(
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Aco.alias'=>'controllers',
                    'Aco.alias'=>'admin_index',
                    'Aco.alias'=>'admin_edit',
                    'Aco.alias'=>'admin_delete'
                )
                ),
            array('order' => 'Aco.lft ASC', 'recursive' => 1));
        debug($result);
```

May I ask you to correct my request?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use array like this:

```
$conditions = array('controllers','admin_index','admin_edit','admin_delete');

$result = $this->Acl->Aco->find(
            'all', 
            array(
                'conditions'=> array('Aco.alias'=>$conditions)
                ),
            array('order' => 'Aco.lft ASC', 'recursive' => 1));
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I may want now to invert my rerquest a go depher to filter. See me second question/answer.

Comment: Here is the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Aco.alias' in 'where clause'. This error is "normal" because it should go deepther into the array. And this I do not know how to do it

Comment: In your find condition, you are using two models named Acl and Aro. 
And in where condition you are using the column of Aco model, thats why this error is coming.

Comment: But this I know, but my question how can I go deepther into the array apply a condition to Aco because the Aco are display (look at my [quote]